# MongoDB C++ String encoding error on accent when inserting JSON string

Tags: c++, json, string, mongodb, character-encoding

I have a problem when I insert a JSON string in MongoDB a C++ function. I am basically creating a big `std::string` formatted as a JSON and I put my values in it.

I have some accents in strings in the data I put in the JSON and I get an error when I try to see the document correctly in the DB after.

This is my update/insert code

```
mongodb_client_connector.update
    (
    mongodb_database+"."+MONGODB_COLLECTION, 
    Query(BSON(MONGODB_ID << OID(param_oid))), 
    fromjson(The_JSON_I_Wrote)
    );
```

This is the result:

[image]

How do I format the string correctly so I get the accents?

Comment: You might want to show us The_JSON_I_Wrote because that is likely the problem.

Comment: If possible, don't construct the document from a string - you will miss out on having non-json bson types like dates without work better done by creating the document using the driver. If you have to use a string, put it in UTF-8 and verify it's correctly encoded.

Comment: I use the date function and it's done correctly. I just write the `"field : new Date(timeInMs)"`. But I have to use a string to pass it to the mongodb C++ driver. So i was wondering how i can translate the string i have in a UTF-8 string.